# ZERO DownTime Deployment of application with frequent database DDL change

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, design-patterns, architecture, cloud

Hi I am trying to deploy my application with zero downtime. My app is quite frequent with database ddl changes. What are all the possible ways to achieve it with zero transaction failure in the app. Though we can use kubernetes to achieve zero downtime of the application, I don't want any failures in service request happening at the time of deployment due to database change like dropping the columns, dropping the table and changing the datatype

TechStack

Kubernetes - Deployment
Spring boot Java -app
Oracle -database

Comment: You have to be extremely careful to make sure any schema changes are backwards compatible to all currently deployed versions. There is no specific one answer for that. You can't drop or rename things until they aren't used.

Comment: What specific problems do you have with doing as you describe? It should be possible. You need to describe your problems.

Comment: No one has ever achieved "zero downtime", and no one likely ever will. Strive for something realistic like three-9s, or four-9s if you're ambitious.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with Kubernetes. You will have the same problems or challenges when you install your application on bare metal servers, on VMs or on plain Docker. Have a look at https://spring.io/blog/2016/05/31/zero-downtime-deployment-with-a-database this describes the problem pretty good.